# how to save and load shared preference towards an other page in flutter

Tags: sharedpreferences, flutter

I tried to Save and share a variable Phone number string from a tabbar page to homepage. Currently my variable is display only after reload. I tried to display variable just after saved it.

my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
   );
 }
}
 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

 final String title;

 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
  }
  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  String _variable;


 @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
   _loadvariable(); 
  }


  _loadvariable() async {   // load variable
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     setState(() {
     _variable = (prefs.getString('variable'));
     }
  );
 }

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(widget.title),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    color: Colors.blue,
    elevation: 20.0,
    child: ButtonBar(
      alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(

          icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Phone_Page()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
   ),

  body: new Center(
    child: new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[

        new Text(
          '$_variable',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
          ),
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
  }
 }
```

here is my seconde page class, I can clic on the phone icon to show a dialog box, and I can write on the text field. After clic on save button my textfield is save, the dialog box is close and my variable is display on the card. But after return on the Homepage my variable isn't display. I need to reload the app to display it :(

```
class Phone_Page extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
Phone_PageState createState() => Phone_PageState();
 }
class Phone_PageState extends State<Phone_Page>   {

 final TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
 String _variable;



 _loadvariable() async {     // load variable
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {

   _variable = (prefs.getString('variable'))?? "";
  });
 }

 _savevariable() async {     // save variable 
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
  prefs.setString('variable', controller.text);
  });
 }

_deletevariable() async {   //delete variable 
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
  prefs.remove('variable');
 });
}


 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 _loadvariable()?? "";
 }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Phone"),
    ),
    body: new Center(
        child: new ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Card(
                child: new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: new Row(
                    children: [
                      new Expanded(
                        child: new Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [

                            new Text(
                              '$_variable',
                                 style: new TextStyle(
                                 color: Colors.grey[500],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                            new IconButton(
                               icon: new Icon(Icons.add_call),
                               onPressed: ()
                            {
                            _showDialog();
                            }
                            ),

                      new IconButton(
                        icon: new Icon(Icons.delete),
                        onPressed: () { setState(() {
                          _deletevariable();
                          _savevariable();
                          _loadvariable();
                          }
                         );
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]
        )
    )
 );
}



_showDialog() async {
  await showDialog<String>(
  context: context,
  child: new AlertDialog(
    // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    content: new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(
          child: new TextField(
            controller: controller,
            autofocus: true,

            decoration: new InputDecoration(

                labelText: 'number', hintText: '06 - - - - - - - -'),
            // keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),

    actions: <Widget>[

      new FlatButton(
          child: const Text('save'),
          onPressed: (){
            setState(() { {
              _savevariable();

              Navigator.pop(context);
              }
             }
            );
          }
        )
       ],
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS36gBEp8OI
i think you are looking for some kinda app state management . check this. There's also redux or you can simply hold the variable on a top level widget(mentioned in video i guess)

Comment: thank you for the link, I see and I will try to implement stream, but it's not very easy for me to underestand :)  
if someone have a  small example of stream to test it with a textfield, 
it would save me time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to call `_loadvariable()` function of class `MyHomePage` from `PhonePage` class. To do that:

Refactor and remove `_` from `_loadvariable()` and `_MyHomePageState` so that it won't be private anymore.
Pass `MyHomePageState` class instance to `PhonePage` as follows:

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new PhonePage(
    myHomePageState: this,
    )),
);
```

Call loadvariable() in _savevariable() like

```
_savevariable() async {
// save variable
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
setState(() {
    prefs.setString('variable', controller.text);
});
widget.myHomePageState.loadvariable();
}
```

Make sure the myHomePageState type is var so that you won't get type error:

```
class PhonePage extends StatefulWidget {
    var myHomePageState;
    PhonePage({this.myHomePageState});
    @override
    PhonPageState createState() => PhonPageState();
}
```